# Getting different result while calculating difference of time in android

Tags: android, datetime

I am fetching  time values from two EditTexts and what the total time spent but this is not working as expected. Can anyone help me for this ?

```
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    try {
        dateOne = format.parse(strFromVessel);
        dateTwo = format.parse(strToVessel);
        System.out.println("date1" + dateOne + "date2" + dateTwo);


        long diff = Math.abs(dateTwo.getTime() - dateOne.getTime());
        System.out.println("diff"+diff);
        System.out.println("dateTwo.getTime()"+dateTwo.getTime());
        System.out.println("dateo.getTime()"+dateOne.getTime());

        long Hours = diff/(1000 * 60 * 60);
        long Mins = diff % (1000*60*60);

        String difference = Hours + ":" + Mins; 
        System.out.println("long"+difference);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what is your expectation and what is result

Comment: @GopalRao that is not correct

Comment: @ Mark Buikema I am getting 1:60000 as output for difference of 13:57 and 14:58

Answer (score 0):

ohk i will give u a example which a make in my code i take diff of time which is current and from 1 jan 1970 i calculate time diff like this may this will help u just put your time instead of my time rest of all code as it is use

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
    DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");  
    date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); 
    String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime); 

    long currenttime = Constant.retunlongdate(localTime);
    long fixtimejan = Constant.retunlongdate("01/01/1970 00:00:00 AM");

    long nTimeStamp = (currenttime - fixtimejan)/1000;
    System.out.println("and result is == " + nTimeStamp);

 public static long retunlongdate(String givenDateString)
        {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"); 

        long timeInMilliseconds=0;
        try {
            Date mDate =sdf.parse(givenDateString);
              timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
            System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
            return timeInMilliseconds;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return timeInMilliseconds;
    }
```

Comment: only time I have I want time diff

Comment: yes exactly but u have to calculate it from longtimemillis dear and my method do same

Comment: but the problem is I am not getting expected result

Comment: its wrong method which is u use pooja coz time have to alll info with it then only u take diff from to time

Comment: just understand if u take time 12.00 of today date and secound date is 12.01 of tommarow then can time diff is only 1 mint ?? no it will be 1 day and 1 mint time understand what i try to tell